# Checking same column values in two different csv files

Tags: python, data-analysis

I am having three different csv files. All three has same column and column names. But the rows values are different. Each csv has a column called user id. I need to count that how many users present in the 1st csv files is not present in the 2nd csv files. Likewise I have to compare between 1st and 2nd, 2nd and 3rd, 1st and 3rd. So how it can be done?

I tried using

```
import csv  
import pandas as pd

file1 =  '25th Feb.csv'  
file2 =  '4th March.csv'

with open(file1) as fp1:  
root = csv.reader(fp1)  
rows1 = {}  
for i in root:  
    rows1[i[0]]=i  
if "User Id" in rows1:  
    del rows1["User Id"]  

with open(file2) as fp1:  
root = csv.reader(fp1)  
rows2 = {}  
for i in root:  
    rows2[i[0]]=i  
if "User Id" in rows2:  
    del rows2["User Id"]  

result = set(rows1.keys()).intersection(set(rows2.keys()))

print (list(result))
```

And I am getting only like this
[]

Comment: It can be done with python!  What have you tried? If you search here for 'Python read from CSV' and 'Python compare lists' I'm sure you'll find what you need.

Comment: *"problem is no. of rows ... are different "*: [Edit] your Question and show with your tried code, **why** ist this a problem to you?